# get buttons next to the one that was clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a checkers game on windows form with C#.
[this is my 4x4 checkers board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmDX9.jpg)

I am using Buttons (which I guess are not the best choice here).

Let's say that the yellow button is the one that was clicked and I want to disable every button except C1 and C3.

I am still a beginner so I am not sure if it's possible at all, but what I want is to find buttons next to the one that was clicked

Here is my code to check which button was clicked:

```
 private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        if ((b.Text == "W") && (turn == true))
        {
            b.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a **Naming Convention** for the Buttons in your Grid that allows you to identify which row/col was clicked?...and then also develop a string that corresponds to a specific position (like maybe "btn_02_03")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to find button somewhere on the screen is definitely possible, but not the easiest way to go. It is better to generate them and store into some convenient structure as they are created:

```
int xCount = 4;
int yCount = 4;
int buttonSize = 40;
Dictionary<Button, Point> pointByButton = new Dictionary<Button, Point>();

for (int x = 0; x < xCount; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < yCount; ++y)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Location = new Point(100 + x * buttonSize, 150 + y * buttonSize);
        newButton.Size = new Size(buttonSize, buttonSize);
        newButton.Name = "" + (char)(y + 'A') + (x + 1);
        newButton.Text = newButton.Name;
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);

        pointByButton.Add(newButton, new Point(x, y));

        newButton.Click += new EventHandler((s, ev) =>
        {
            Point thisPoint = pointByButton[(Button)s];

            foreach (var btn in pointByButton)
            {
                if (btn.Value.Y - thisPoint.Y != -1 || Math.Abs(btn.Value.X - thisPoint.X) != 1)
                {
                    btn.Key.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried it and it works jut like I wanted. The problem is that I am just a beginner so I have a bit of trouble understanding this code especially the 2nd part. But thanks anyway this is really helpful and I think as soon as I wrap my head around it I will be able to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have got your answer (and that is the correct answer), I highly recommend you learn the `Object Oriented` ways of programming things. In `OOP`, you visualize your objects as real world objects. In a nutshell, they have state (Properties), exhibit behavior (Methods) and respond to stimuli (Events). You can also take one object, throw in some more properties/methods/events and carve out a new object from it (Inheritance).

When I was learning and programmed my first chess game, I did it somewhat like this:

1. Add a new class to our project that represents a `Cell` on our game board. Lets call it `CheckersCell`. We make it inherit from `Button` (I used `Label` in my original version`). Then we add a new property to it to hold its Position (co-ordinates) on the board.

> ```
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> class CheckersCell : Button
> {
>     public Point Position { get; set; }
> }
> ```

2. Next we add another class (`CheckersBoard`) that represents the game board. It contains all the 64 cells (CheckersCell). The `SetupBoard()` method creates the cells and arranges the cells in order. The `GetAdjescentCell` method gives you information about the surrounding cells relative to a cell on the board.

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
> using System.ComponentModel;
>
> [DefaultEvent("CellClick")]
> class CheckersBoard : Panel
> {
>     public const int BoardSize = 8; // for standard 8x8 board
>     public enum Direction { Left, Right, Up, Down, LeftUp, LeftDown, RightUp, RightDown }
>
>     public event EventHandler CellClick = new EventHandler((s, e) => { });
>
>     public CheckersCell[] Cells { get; set; }
>
>     public CheckersBoard()
>     {
>         SetupBoard();
>     }
>
>     public CheckersCell GetCellByPosition(int x, int y)
>     {
>         foreach (CheckersCell cell in Cells)
>         {
>             if (cell.Position.X == x && cell.Position.Y == y) return cell;
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     protected void SetupBoard()
>     {
>         // setup the board
>         Cells = new CheckersCell[BoardSize * BoardSize];
>         int cellNumber = 0;
>         for (int x = 0; x < BoardSize; x++)
>         {
>             for (int y = 0; y < BoardSize; y++)
>             {
>                 CheckersCell currentCell = new CheckersCell();
>                 Cells[cellNumber++] = currentCell;
>                 this.Controls.Add(currentCell);
>                 currentCell.Name = string.Concat(this.Name, "Cell", x, "x", y);
>                 currentCell.Position = new Point(x + 1, y + 1);
>                 currentCell.BackColor = ((x + y) % 2 == 0) ? Color.Brown : Color.White;
>                 currentCell.Click += (s, e) => { CellClick(s, e); };
>             }
>         }
>         OnResize(null);
>     }
>
>     public CheckersCell GetAdjescentCell(CheckersCell referenceCell, Direction d)
>     {
>         return GetAdjescentCell(referenceCell, d, 1);
>     }
>
>     public CheckersCell GetAdjescentCell(CheckersCell referenceCell, Direction d, int steps)
>     {
>         // find the co-ordinates of adjescent cell we want to go to
>         Point newPosition = referenceCell.Position;
>         switch (d)
>         {
>             case Direction.Left:
>                 newPosition.X -= steps; break;
>             case Direction.Right:
>                 newPosition.X += steps; break;
>             case Direction.Up:
>                 newPosition.Y -= steps; break;
>             case Direction.Down:
>                 newPosition.Y += steps; break;
>             case Direction.LeftUp:
>                 newPosition.X -= steps; newPosition.Y -= steps; break;
>             case Direction.RightUp:
>                 newPosition.X += steps; newPosition.Y -= steps; break;
>             case Direction.LeftDown:
>                 newPosition.X -= steps; newPosition.Y += steps; break;
>             case Direction.RightDown:
>                 newPosition.X += steps; newPosition.Y += steps; break;
>         }
>         foreach (CheckersCell cell in Cells)
>         {
>             if (cell.Position == newPosition) return cell;
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs eventargs)
>     {
>         base.OnResize(eventargs);
>         int cellWidth = this.Width / BoardSize;
>         int cellHeight = this.Height / BoardSize;
>         foreach (CheckersCell cell in Cells)
>         {
>             cell.Size = new Size(cellWidth, cellHeight);
>             cell.Location = new Point((cell.Position.X - 1) * cellWidth, (cell.Position.Y - 1) * cellHeight);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

That's all we need to set it up (w.r.t your question). Lets test what we have.

After you compile your project, you will see two new items in the Toolbox - `CheckersBoard` and `CheckersCell`. Drag `CheckersBoard` on to your form and resize it to your wish.

[image: Checkers Board]

Double-click anywhere on the board. It will open the Form code, with a method (event) named `checkersBoard1_CellClick`. Put the following code in that method:

```
    private void checkersBoard1_CellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckersCell cell = (CheckersCell)sender;
        string msg = "";
        msg += "You clicked on Cell : " + cell.Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "Left : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.Left).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "Right : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.Right).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "Up : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.Up).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "Down : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.Down).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "UpLeft : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.LeftUp).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "UpRight : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.RightUp).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "DownLeft : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.LeftDown).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        msg += "DownRight : " + checkersBoard1.GetAdjescentCell(cell, CheckersBoard.Direction.RightDown).Position.ToString() + "\n";
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

Save everything, compile and run. Click any cell on the board (don't click the corner rows or columns since this is just meant for a demo). It should show a message box that looks somewhat like this:

[image: message box]

HTH.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried to use this code you wrote and it worked really well, the problem is as I have already stated before I am a complete beginner  and I don't understand most of the things you wrote there, but I am sure it is the right way to go with my task. The thing is I'm on a tight schedule so I have a week to finish this project and I am not sure I could learn enough about OOP to do anything with it so I just went with a jagged array for my labels and it works quite well (for now at least). Thanks for your input.